# GUI error in Android

Tags: android, error-handling

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nCreateTreeFromCopy(JJ)J
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.nCreateTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.access$400(VectorDrawable.java:204)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createNativeTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java:837)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.<init>(VectorDrawable.java:812)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.mutate(VectorDrawable.java:268)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:817)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:329)
    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable$AnimatedStateListState.addStateSet(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:602)
    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.parseItem(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:525)
    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:453)
    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflate(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:385)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1224)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1197)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:315)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:681)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:89)
    at android.widget.RadioButton.<init>(RadioButton.java:63)
    at android.widget.RadioButton.<init>(RadioButton.java:59)
    at android.widget.RadioButton.<init>(RadioButton.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor336.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:107)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:149)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:317)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: My android studio is showing rendering problem when i insert any widget in layout. This is the detailed error. Any help will be useful.

Comment: This is the stack trace shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known reported [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37112806) in an older version of android studio. You can see the status of the ticket **"Won't Fix (Obsolete)"**. So you may either need to upgrade to the latest Android SDK or try to change the preview API to any other version.

*Android studio automatically pick best by default*, So you have to select another version manually.

[image]